# Usable, free ISO file editor that runs on Windows?

Tags: windows, mount, iso-image

I need a free (libre) utility for Windows that allows a person to edit an ISO file.

The goal is to be able to:

- Mount the ISO file with the ISO filesystem being readable and writeable.
- Make changes to files in the ISO filesystem as needed via the utility.
- Unmount the ISO filesystem with changes being saved to the ISO file.

How can I do this?  Is there a utility, or do I need to build a toolchain?

Comment: @matt wilkie do you have a Winrar registered version?

Comment: No @avirk, I don't. I generally use 7zip. Why, does registered winrar edit ISOs?

Comment: @random, please elucidate why this was closed as not constructive. The question is clear, well worded, and specific. I fail to see what parts of it might solicit debate or argument. The question has been upvoted 10 times and been made a favourite 5 times, demonstrating strong interest in the answers.

Comment: It's shopping for a product recommendation. That goes either off topic or not constructive @mat

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification @random. I can see how asking for product recommendations can be perceived as off topic. I think this is on the edge of that and not in it, but I accept it. You should close this one too then: http://superuser.com/questions/3804/free-windows-iso-mounting-software?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the other question. These are better rephrased by asking how to do an action in a current app. With the comment or aside saying that you're open for other programs, but the primary goal would be to fix/better the current app @mat

Comment: @random: Just for curiosity - how does one ask for an iso editor (=software) as "an action in a current app" when one has none?

Comment: Fetching a list of apps to try or not try would clearly be a polling/shopping question that can't be asked @har

Comment: @random: I'm not trying to be difficult, but I must admit I don't understand. The FAQ says "shopping or buying", but this cannot apply to freeware. Polling isn't mentioned, but even if it was the dictionary makes it almost synonymous with voting, and certainly there was no voting requested here or an opinion poll. How is asking for recommendation same as polling? And remarking that SU, by its vote system, is nothing else than an opinion poll system.

Comment: You could try http://superuser.com/a/656024/159726

Comment: **For future reference:** If you want a software recommendation (which is what you need if you don't have any apps that you currently know can do this) try asking here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no "free (libre) utility" that does all this.

You can use **[7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip)** to extract ISO images, **[WinCDEmu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinCDEmu)** to mount an ISO image and **[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)** rebuild and write the ISO image to disc.

*7-Zip, WinCDEmu and InfraRecorder are free open source programs (which is pretty much as 'libre' as it gets :). Portable versions of 7-Zip and InfraRecorder are available.*

Comment: InfraRecorder cannot view/edit ISOs, only burn them.

Comment: https://anyburn.com/ is completely free and "edits" iso by opening one, letting you add/remove files then makes a copy of the new ISO. Does not modify in place, and for that matter I think most software creates a temporary file anyway before modifying the image.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any free software that allows you to mount an ISO as a read/write drive.  ImgBurn though is a free tool that will allow you to extract the contents of an ISO, then modify the files, then re-create the ISO.

Comment: I tried ImgBurn today. It's closed-source and adware-ridden. I've uninstalled it.

Comment: Yes, when I originally posted this, although it was closed source, it wasn't full of adverts.  It has since gained more and more adverts so I'm also looking for an alternative.

Comment: I've used InfraRecorder and am quite happy. It's open source and has all the features I want.

Comment: `Poweriso +  MagicISO  + UltraISO  + WinISO` (filesize limit);


`ISOpen` (FREE);


`SecureCD creator` (FREE);


`ISO master` +  `gBurner` (trial period);

Answer (score 3):

**UltraISO**: On June 2009, PC User magazine Australia offered v9 full version to its readers.

Here are the registration details:

```
Name: PC User readers
Serial: 4BF9-8D1E-1786-30A8
```

Do take note that this registration details will NOT work on the trial installer that is downloadable from UltraISO's website, but the original version can still be found by googling for `uiso93pes.exe`.

[**TotalMounter**](http://www.kernsafe.com/product/totalmounter.aspx) is advertised as a free ISO editor, but I have no experience with it.

[**Folder2Iso**](http://www.trustfm.net/divx/SoftwareFolder2Iso.php) does what it is named for and can be used instead of an ISO editor.

Comment: is there a citation for the PC User magazine offering? ...just thinking it would be a good idea to back the claim up, making it clear this isn't warez or similar.

Comment: This UltraISO freebie is plastered all over the Internet, but impossible to find out its source, since PC User was apparently sold. One source is [here](http://forum.raymond.cc/freebies/12282-free-ultraiso-v9-full-license-key.html).

Comment: Re: Folder2Iso; the Folder2Iso page itself says clearly *About : Folder2Iso just creates an iso from any kind of folder (with the subfolders).* Nothing about *editing*.   Re: TotalMounter; Cool. A virtual CDVD-RW software has been elusive for a long time. My only concern is with the terrible writing on the page. It looks like a non-native English-speaker wrote it, but there is no indication of the company being foreign. Oh, also, it seems to be free due to [built-in ads](http://www.kernsafe.com/Products/TotalMounter/Screenshot/Main.Png).

Comment: @Synetech: Folder2Iso: I just wanted to mention it as last possibility, when having no other solution, to edit the folder and then create the ISO. Not the best, but at least free.

Answer (score 1):

**New answer:**

There's practically no all-in-one utility to achieve this on Windows, although some alternatives for Linux exist. Your best bet is to extract the files, change them and them generate a new ISO, or work with [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip).

---

Old, but updated answer:

You clearly state that you want to mount and then edit your image file. So:

- For a **FOSS/Libre** utility, try [ISO Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_Master) or [AcetoneISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acetoneiso/).
- I'd suggest using a freeware or even shareware utility, like 7-Zip, MagicISO, etc.

Comment: An old question but I recently stirred the pot as I'm looking for updated answers. :) The feature set of AcetoneISO looks rich, but is linux only and this Q is specifically for Windows. 7zip has already been mentioned. MagicISO is new to this thread, mentions editing as a feature, but while inexpensive is not free.

Comment: Is AcetoneIso a free iso editor? maybe not..

Comment: @Solutioner: It's FOSS although it's not an editor indeed. Best and probably only free alternative for windows is 7Zip. ISO Master is free for linux and shareware for Windows but you have to find it on download sites such as softpedia. So, either one uses a shareware utility (lots of them: WinISO, MagicISO, PowerISO) or extracts the iso, changes the files, and creates a new one. No easy and free all-in-one solution exists (let alone a portable one...).