# How to edit bootable ISO for free?

Tags: windows, iso-image

Under Windows, is there any way to edit the contents of a bootable ISO for free?

*(Note: I am not interested in commercial software, but want free iso editor functionality)*

Comment: best I can find is to mount the file using a preferred method, copy the contents, edit as desired and recreate the iso file using something like Free ISO Creator (http://www.minidvdsoft.com/).

Comment: thanks, that's what I already do, but I was looking for better options

Comment: The only other thing I found that might come close (don't have anything here to really test with) is ImageMaster (http://www.freewarebb.com/files/file/7110-imagemaster/). It doesn't look like it does direct edits, but it can read, extract, create, burn all from the same interface, so you only need the one program.

Comment: Isn't this question about software recommendation? I thought it is off-topic here(and why I couldn't edit the comment in time: the GFW)...

Answer (score 21):

## FREE ISO Editor

*(by 2016)*

**Method 1**:

- Use [**SecureCD creator**](https://www.kernsafe.com/download/SecureCDCreator2.0.exe). It is free ISO editor & ALL-IN-ONE solution! *(You wont need [premium features](https://www.kernsafe.com/product/securecd-creator/license-compares.aspx). However, it is [free too](https://www.kernsafe.com/faq/how-to-get-free-license.aspx))*

**Method 2**:

- Download [WinIso](https://www.winiso.com/products/winiso-free.html)  (Trial version make modification only max.100mb file). However, you can freely **EXTRACT** any iso file, then modify it as you need, then :
- Download [ImgBurn](https://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/Data-CD-DVD-Burning/ImgBurn.shtml) and [create a bootable ISO from extracted folder](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-re-create-a-bootable-iso-from-extracted-windows-installation-files).  (Instead of ImgBurn you can also use [Folder-ISO-creator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iso-creator-cs/) or [Folder2Iso](https://www.trustfm.net/software/utilities/Folder2Iso.php), but I am not sure if they can create **bootable** images).

**Method 3** (untested by me)

- [TotalMounter](https://www.kernsafe.com/download/TotalMounter2.01.exe) (free) is said to do the job

**Method 4** (untested by me)

- there also exists **ISOpen** (FREE) that claims to modify ISO files directly, but latest version seemed crap/non-working/malicious to me... Do at your own risk, or test only in VirtualBox windows as recommended for crap apps.);

## == Commercial(Trial) software ==

- [gBurner](https://www.gburner.com/download.htm) ( during 30 day trial period, you can modify ANYTHING! after that, only 300mb files);
- [ISO master](https://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/CD-DVD-Images-Utils/ISO-Master.shtml) +  [Poweriso](https://www.poweriso.com/download.php) +  [MagicISO](https://www.magiciso.com/download.htm)  + [UltraISO](https://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/download.htm)  + [WinISO](https://www.winiso.com/download.html) (filesize limits, about 300mb);

Comment: gBurner (trial period): - is the only one that works with 2 gig ISO files

Comment: I rejected your edit to the title of this question primarily because it changed the question to sound like it was asking for product recommendations. Such a change would have made the question off-topic on this site, while in its current form it is simply asking for *solutions*.

Comment: Mokubai, I cant agree with you. You can easily see, that he is not asking for solutions (because he has already found what he was searching - a way to edit `iso` file), but he tries to find solutions, that are FREE ones. So, my request was only to include that word in TITLE, otherwise, the whole question is absurd, because he says that he has `.iso editor` already.

Comment: +1 for gBurner. Tried SecureCD creator, but after I added a file to the ISO and saved it was no longer bootable. This worked in gBurner.

Comment: Neither method 1 nor method 3 worked for me to edit an ISO image. SecureCD did could not open a bootable Windows ISO and looks a bit dated in general. And TotalMounter actually caused a blue screen crash on trying to open an ISO.

Answer (score 5):

[WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/), [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) and [imgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) all let you open and edit files, although WinRAR is paid for (eventually, that is).

Comment: Winrar can actually be used forever..it prompts you to register, but you can still use it anyway.

Comment: I tried WinRAR / 7zip >> both can open Iso files , but can't edit (add/delete) any files within. MagicISO >> limited to 300mb .  imgBurn >> can create/burn but cant "EDIT"

Comment: You could use 7zip to open the files, extract them, then reacreate it using ImgBurn...but there's probably more efficent ways to do so.

Comment: @TazoTodua this answer was posted over five years ago, back in 2011...

Comment: @tombull89 ISO won't be bootable anymore

Answer (score 5):

I just came across a program which did this for me: [ISO Master](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Environment/File-managers/ISO-Master-16676.shtml)

Only thing is, it's Linux-only. I searched for Windows-based software for two days but did not come across anything that could edit a bootable ISO file.

Answer (score 5):

[AnyBurn](http://www.anyburn.com/) can do it. It lets you modify the contents of an ISO image. It supports bootable images: it can add, remove or keep boot information.

Answer (score 2):

[Image Master](http://www.softsea.com/review/Image-Master.html) or [Deep Burner](http://www.deepburner.com/?r=download) seems to be the windows solutions to ISO Master.

I would use 7-zip to extract the ISO, hack about with this, [LC ISO Creator](http://www.deepburner.com/?r=download) and then either ImgBurn to burn the ISO or [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) to mount it.

Comment: I've also used WinCDEmu in place of ImDisk.

Answer (score 1):

I use WinISO - [www.winiso.com/download.html](http://www.winiso.com/download.html)

The free version will only let you save ISOs of 500mb max