# "The product key entered does not match any of the Windows image"

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

I have a HP with Windows 7 installed. I want to do a clean installation of Windows 8 from a bootable DVD.

I purchased my Windows 8 32-bit core from the Microsoft store and I received my product key. I then burned the .ISO file to a blank DVD using imgburn. When I restart and change my BIOS to boot from internal CD/DVD and then boot from my internal DVD, I start the installation process.

After I pass the screen where I select the language and location, and click *Install* it stays there for a minute and then it says:

> The product key entered does not match any of the Windows image

I did my research and learned that I need to add a `PID.txt` file to my source file containing the Windows 8 .ISO but the thing is: I do not know how to add files to the .ISO. The guide I researched is for a bootable USB and I am using a DVD.

Comment: windows 8 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: windows 8 32bit

Comment: There are multiple utilities out there (PowerISO, MagicISO, WinISO, ISOBuster, etc) that will allow you to edit an ISO file.  Unfortunately none of them are free.  WinISO has a free version, but it will only edit CD images, not DVD images.  This question however, http://superuser.com/questions/77016/usable-free-iso-file-editor-that-runs-on-windows does have an answer with the tools you can use to manually edit and recreate the ISO.

Comment: For people who found this question but are trying to install windows 10 -- Just delete sources/ei.cfg. That's it! It'll install fine after that. There's no PID.txt. That's only for windows 10 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps :

If its Usb

1.Open `Notepad`

2.Create a `text file` with the name of `PID.Text`

3.Put the following in the file

```
[PID] Value=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

4.Replace `XXX` with your `product Key`

5.Place into your `/sources` File of your `iso`

6.Reburn the Iso

For DVD From [Windows valley](http://www.windowsvalley.com/unlock-all-editions-from-windows-7-iso-image-x86-and-x64/) create an Unlock Disc

Use 7-zip to extract that ISO to a particular folder and go to Source folder and look for ei.cfg file.

```
EI.cfg is a Windows Setup-specific configuration file used to determine what edition and license will be used during installation. This file replaces PID.txt and is located on the product media under the Sources folder in Windows Vista DVD
```

To get desired edition-

3.Use Notepad to edit and save this file by change desired EditionID. Valid EditionIDs are:

Edit ei.cfg file

```
Ulimate
Professional
HomePremium
HomeBasic
Starter
```

To get all editions-

4.Just delete the file and finally create the bootable ISO and burn your unlocked disc.

Comment: the thing is after i add the file to my source how do i convert the file back to .ISO am using image burn and its giving me a hard time

Comment: @MarilynLacey use any iso maker to convert back to iso,many tools like ultraiso ,magiciso,isobuster were present for this

Comment: Why didn't you include the EditionID called Enterprise?

Comment: `PID.txt` rather than `PID.Text` according to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824952.aspx. And `Value` on a newline, although it could work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if the solution with PID.txt does not work - try creating

> ei.cfg

and write in it:

> [Channel]
> Retail
>
> [VL]
> 0

put into "sources" folder.

Keep in mind to delete PID.TXT file if You have it.

Regards!