# browse a library of iso without mounting each iso

Tags: mount, iso-image

I have a library of iso images of older CD-ROM of media and of software.  I am not sure if this is the best way to store legacy media and software... please speak out if you have another solution.  but my question here is whether there is a way to browse for a certain file in one of these iso's without having to mount each and every one of them?  - something like tar -t where it lists the content of the tar package without un-tarring the whole tar package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usable, free ISO file editor that runs on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/77016/usable-free-iso-file-editor-that-runs-on-windows), [How do I edit bootable ISO files in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/333870/how-do-i-edit-bootable-iso-files-in-windows?lq=1)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Not exactly a duplicate as the OP mentions `tar -t` which is not a Windows command. My guess is that OP is using Linux, but (s)he needs to clarify that.

Comment: Ahh the lack of a OS tag/mention may have gotten me.

Comment: sorry about the lack of OS... But linux type is what i am looking for.  i currently use ubuntu and MAC (Terminal- i.e. freebsd linux)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `7z` program from p7zip is able to list the contents of CD images:

```
$ 7z l ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Listing archive: ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso

--
Path = ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso
Type = Iso
Created = 2014-04-16 23:12:51
Modified = 2014-04-16 23:12:51

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2014-04-16 23:11:55 D....                            .disk
2014-04-16 23:11:55 .....            0            0  .disk/base_installable
2014-04-16 23:11:55 .....           15           15  .disk/cd_type
2014-04-16 23:11:55 .....           66           66  .disk/info
2014-04-16 23:12:44 D....                            EFI
2014-04-16 23:12:44 D....                            EFI/BOOT
2014-04-16 23:12:44 .....      1355736      1355736  EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
2014-04-16 23:12:44 .....       993144       993144  EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi
2014-04-16 23:11:55 .....          236          236  README.diskdefines
2014-04-16 23:12:44 D....                            boot
2014-04-16 23:12:44 D....                            boot/grub
...
2014-03-23 17:09:32 .....        79582        79582  pool/main/z/zope.interface/python-zope.interface_4.0.5-1ubuntu4_amd64.deb
2014-04-16 23:11:55 D....                            preseed
2013-10-18 16:56:44 .....          433          433  preseed/cli.seed
2013-10-18 16:56:44 .....          659          659  preseed/cloud.seed
2013-10-18 16:56:44 .....          901          901  preseed/ubuntu-server-minimal.seed
2013-10-18 16:56:44 .....          931          931  preseed/ubuntu-server-minimalvm.seed
2013-10-18 16:56:44 .....          977          977  preseed/ubuntu-server.seed
                    .....         2048         2048  [BOOT]/Bootable_NoEmulation.img
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                             590842085    590842085  1932 files, 882 folders
```

Another program for listing the contents is `isoinfo` from cdrkit:

```
$ isoinfo -l -i ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso

Directory listing of /
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     20 02]  . 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     20 02]  .. 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     22 02]  .DISK 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     23 02]  BOOT 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     41 02]  DISTS 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     55 02]  DOC 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     64 02]  EFI 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     66 02]  INSTALL 
d---------   0    0    0           18432 Apr 16 2014 [     73 02]  ISOLINUX 
----------   0    0    0          162102 Apr 16 2014 [   2349 00]  MD5SUM.TXT;1 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     82 02]  PICS 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     83 02]  POOL 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [    976 02]  PRESEED 
----------   0    0    0             236 Apr 16 2014 [   1923 00]  README.DISKDEFINES;1 
----------   0    0    0               0 Apr 16 2014 [   1920 00]  UBUNTU.;1 

Directory listing of /.DISK/
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 16 2014 [     22 02]  .
...
----------   0    0    0          152976 Apr 15 2014 [   8789 00]  VESAMENU.C32;1 

Directory listing of /INSTALL/NETBOOT/UBUNTU_INSTALLER/AMD64/PXELINUX.CFG/
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 15 2014 [     72 02]  . 
d---------   0    0    0            2048 Apr 15 2014 [     69 02]  .. 
----------   0    0    0               0 Apr 15 2014 [   1920 00]  DEFAULT.;1
```

Comment: Thanks for this... it looks like what i am looking for... let me test is out

Comment: it does do what i asked for in my question.. so i marked as answer... thanks again.

Comment: Another tool is `xorriso`. You can run `xorriso -dev ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso -find . -exec lsdl` It behaves like `find`, so you can get pretty creative with your listing.